# Binding the placeholder to the model causes ng-change to execute on load in IE

Tags: angularjs

Using angularjs, if I bind the placeholder of an input to its model, the change event is fired when the document loads in IE.  This does not appear to be correct and I'm not seeing this behavior in other browsers.

[JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VxBNW/6/)

Html:

```
<div ng-app="angularjs-starter" data-ng-controller="MainCtrl">
<div data-ui-view="viewMain">
    <input 
    placeholder="{{theValue}}" 
    data-ng-model="theValue" 
    data-ng-change="valueChanged(theValue)" />            
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {  
    $scope.valueChanged = function(theValue) {
        alert("Value Change Called On Load in IE.");
    };
});
```

Answer (score 11):

It's possible to use the built-in [`ng-attr-placeholder`](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive#-ngattr-attribute-bindings) directive as well.

```
ng-attr-placeholder="{{theValue}}"
```

Answer (score 7):

I know this is old but just in case anyone else runs in to this I created a small directive that goes around putting a dynamic value in the placeholder and instead have it assign when it changes:

```
.directive('dynamicPlaceholder',
    function() {
        return {                
            restrict: 'A',
            link: function ($scope, element, attrs) {
                attrs.$observe('dynamicPlaceholder', function(value) {
                    element.attr('placeholder', value);
                });
            }
        };
    });
```

Then to use this all you need to do is use `dynamic-placeholder` instead of `placeholder`:

```
<input ng-model='someValue' dynamic-placeholder='{{someDynamicPlaceholder}}' />
```

Not sure what is causing the problem in IE though