# ui-select2 placeholder with interpolation in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, interpolation, placeholder, ui-select2

I am using ui-select2 in angularjs application and I want to use dynamic placeholder text, when I tried with below code,

```
<input id="listcategories" type="hidden" data-placeholder= '{{model.placeholderText}}' data-ui-select2="{multiple: false, width:'100%'}" data-model="model" data-ng-model="model.value" data-ng-disabled="model.readOnly" />
```

it is showing like in below image.

[image]

Can someone help me to use dynamic placeholder for ui-select2.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, please make demo so, i can help, your need input type hide or select drop down

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22470089/rendering-a-dynamic-placeholder-with-angular) or [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17286693/binding-the-placeholder-to-the-model-causes-ng-change-to-execute-on-load-in-ie)

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in your HTML page

```
<script>
    /*--  Select 2 Initialization  --*/
    $("#listcategories").select2({placeholder: "Select a font"});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
<select id="listcategories" ng-options="item as item.label for item in items" ng-model="model">
<option value="">{{model.placeholderText}}</option>
</select>
```